# trying to find the right adjective to express "expectations were exceeded"

Tags: word-choice

I am constructing my resume. I had one internship experience where I delivered performance that exceeded their expectations and they wanted me back to work full time after I graduate.

So I want to put this in my resume. I am trying to come up with a sentence like

```
"delivered _ performance and landed a return offer"
```

and I need an adjective to fill in the blank, something like `expectation-exceeding`. But I am not sure if it is even a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there can be an exact adjective here but you can use the idiom 
***beyond (all) expectations***

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beyond%20expectations) :

"more than people thought would be the case:

The restaurant has succeeded beyond (all) expectations."

Comment: so can I say "delivered  beyond-expectations performance and landed a return offer"?

Comment: No, this idiom is used as an adverbial modifier, not an attribute (even hyphenated).

Comment: For example, to deliver performance beyond expectation.

Comment: "delivered performance beyond expectation and landed a return offer" Got it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[Superior](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superior)** of higher rank, quality, or importance.

**[Exceptional](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exceptional)**  better than average.

Or any synonym of the above.